# Add function before checkout with simplecartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplecart

I use Simplecartjs and I see they have custom to add function beforeCheckout.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
simpleCart({

    // array representing the format and columns of the cart, see 
    // the cart columns documentation
    cartColumns: [
        {view:"image" , attr:"thumb", label: false },
        { attr: "name" , label: "Name" },
        { attr: "price" , label: "Price", view: 'currency' },
        { view: "decrement" , label: false },
        { attr: "quantity" , label: "Qty" },
        { view: "increment" , label: false },
        { attr: "total" , label: "SubTotal", view: 'currency' },
        { view: "remove" , text: "Remove" , label: false }
    ],

    // "div" or "table" - builds the cart as a table or collection of divs
    cartStyle: "div", 

    // how simpleCart should checkout, see the checkout reference for more info 
    checkout: { 
        type: "PayPal" , 
        email: "you@hello.com" 
    },

    // set the currency, see the currency reference for more info
    currency: "USD",

    // collection of arbitrary data you may want to store with the cart, 
    // such as customer info
    data: {},

    // set the cart langauge (may be used for checkout)
    language: "english-us",

    // array of item fields that will not be sent to checkout
    excludeFromCheckout: [],

    // custom function to add shipping cost
    shippingCustom: null,

    // flat rate shipping option
    shippingFlatRate: 0,

    // added shipping based on this value multiplied by the cart quantity
    shippingQuantityRate: 0,

    // added shipping based on this value multiplied by the cart subtotal
    shippingTotalRate: 0,

    // tax rate applied to cart subtotal
    taxRate: 0,

    // true if tax should be applied to shipping
    taxShipping: false,

    // event callbacks 
    beforeAdd               : null,
    afterAdd                : null,
    load                    : null,
    beforeSave              : null,
    afterSave               : null,
    update                  : null,
    ready                   : null,
    checkoutSuccess             : null,
    checkoutFail                : null,
    beforeCheckout              : null
});
//]]>
</script>
```

But I do not how to add new function for it. Write new script? For example, add function to alert 5s with content: "You are redirecting to Paypal" before redirect to Paypal.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this

```
simpleCart.bind( 'beforeCheckout' , function( data ){
    alert('You are redirecting to Paypal');
});
```

with timeOut looks like so:

```
simpleCart.bind( 'beforeCheckout' , function( data ){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('You are redirecting to Paypal')
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds
});
```

at the end of the last .js file or create a new .js file which you include as last file:

Comment: It is so helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Marked as best answer :)